# "The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `inputShape` or `batchInputShape` argument." when loading Keras model with TensorFlow.js

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow.js

I trained the following model using [Keras](https://keras.io/) (Version 2.2.4):

```py
# imports ...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Flatten(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Dense(units=256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=8, activation="softmax"))
# training ...
model.save("model.h5")
```

The inputs are 28 x 28 grayscale images of shape`(28, 28, 1)`.

[image: Model Overview]

I converted the model with [`tensorflowjs_converter`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) and now I want to load it in my website using [TensorFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/) (Version 1.1.0):

```js
tf.loadLayersModel('./model/model.json')
```

This produces the following error:

```
The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `inputShape` or `batchInputShape` argument.
    at new e (errors.ts:48)
    at e.add (models.ts:440)
    at e.fromConfig (models.ts:1020)
    at vp (generic_utils.ts:277)
    at nd (serialization.ts:31)
    at models.ts:299
    at common.ts:14
    at Object.next (common.ts:14)
    at o (common.ts:14)
```

How can I fix this error without having to retrain the model?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to train your model if you didn't define an input shape

Comment: @Primusa The training worked and as you can see in the picture above, the right input shape was derived correctly.

Comment: try running your model definition code and actually compile / train it on some dummy data

Comment: @Primusa I did that, and it worked. The loss decreased and the file model.h5 was created. If it hadn't worked, I wouldn't have been able to convert the model.

Comment: perhaps try saving the weights with `model.save_weights`, and then doing `model.load_weights` on an architecture that has the input shape defined, and then saving that model and converting

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your neural net to this format:

```
input_img = Input(batch_shape=(None, 28,28,1))
layer1=Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu")(input_img)
layer2=BatchNormalization()(layer1)
.
.
.
final_layer=Dense(units=8, activation="softmax")(previous_layer)
```

... and so forth. At the end:

```
model = Model(inputs = input_img, outputs = final_layer)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, I'm not quite clear? Do I have to train the model again? Can't this be solved in the JavaScript code?

Comment: You have to adjust the python code, then, convert the model to TensorFlow.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the input shape in the Conv2D layer of your keras model.

```
# imports ...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(28, 28, 1), filters=64, kernel_size=5, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, data_format="channels_last", activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Flatten(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Dense(units=256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=8, activation="softmax"))
# training ...
model.save("model.h5")
```

Comment: I know I should have done it that way in the first place. But the question was whether I could solve the problem afterwards, because I didn't want to train the model again. But that's over now anyway, because I had to change the model's architecture due to overfitting. So I'm not looking for a solution anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to change your keras model and retrain.

Anyway, if you cannot retrain your network, you can manually edit your `model.json` file.

You need to find the input layer in your `model.json` file and add

```
  "config": {
    ...
    "batch_input_shape": [
      null,
      28,
      28,
      1
    ]
    ...
  }
```